# Como adicionar uma coluna com texto no gridview pelo code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Faço um SELECT no banco e monto a minha gridview, após isso faço outro SELECT e 
precisava adicionar uma coluna a mais com os valores que vieram.

Tenho uma ForEach para passar por todas as linhas do segundo SELECT, e outro ForEach para passar em todas as linhas do gridview. Se o nome do curso existir na gridview, teria que adicionar essa nova coluna, com o valor(R$) do curso.

Estou tentando assim, não dá erro, mas também não mostrou a coluna nova.

```
List<Informacoes> list2 = dal.ValorCurso(candidato);

          list2.ForEach(delegate (Informacoes dom)
          {
            string local = list2[dom.INDEX].CURSO;

            foreach (GridViewRow row in this.gvInscricoesCurso.Rows)
            {
              if (local.Contains(row.Cells[0].Text))
              {
                TemplateField template = new TemplateField();
                template.HeaderStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
                template.HeaderText = "Valor do curso";

                gvInscricoesCurso.Columns.Add(template);
              }
            }
          });
```

Alguém teria uma dica de como fazer ou então uma outra maneira?

Para carregar a primeira vez eu faço da seguinte maneira, chamada para a consulta e montagem da gridview:

```
Informacoes informacoes = new Informacoes();

Candidato candidato = new Candidato
{
CodColigada = Convert.ToInt16(ddlInstituicao.SelectedValue.Split('-')[0]),
CodFilial = Convert.ToInt16(ddlInstituicao.SelectedValue.Split('-')[1]),
};

DAL dal = new DAL();

DataTable dtInscritosCurso = dal.TotalInscritosCursoDetalhe(candidato);
gvInscricoesCurso.DataSource = dtInscritosCurso;
gvInscricoesCurso.DataBind();
```

E a minha consulta no banco tem bastante linhas, ficaria muito extenso colocar na pergunta, mas não está retornando nenhum erro.

Comment: Você faz como pra carregar a primeira vez, já vejo problemas no ar ... ?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic editei a pergunta com a maneira que carrego a primeira vez

Comment: Você precisa fazer isso tudo na SQL  ...

Comment: @VirgilioNovic putz, pior é que a minha query que faz a primeira chamada tem 246 e está demorando muito para carregar, por isso queria fazer desta outra maneira..

Comment: 249  chamada o que?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic a query tem 246 linhas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A maneira realmente ideal seria isso não ser tratado na sua interface, e sim fazer com que seu `SELECT` possua um `JOIN` que também receberá esse valor. Como outra opção, tente ao invés de popular a grid com o valor, ter um campo valor no seu objeto candidato. Caso não possua o campo valor, só manter nulo.

Comment: putz, pior é que a minha query que faz a primeira chamada tem 246 e está demorando muito para carregar, por isso queria fazer desta outra maneira..